# radtreeview binding issue in load

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radtreeview

I am trying to bind a radtreeview on page load as below but I am not able to see the radtreeview with binded data on the page, I am able to see the data in the list .ParentId,.Id,.Name,.ParentName

can anyone please look into this ?

```
  < telerik:RadTreeView ID="rtvMyConnections" runat="server" ToolTip="" Skin="DV" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false"  CheckBoxes="true" >
    </telerik:RadTreeView>



Dim lstresult As New List(Of MyEntity)

Dim svcProxy As IConnectionService = CreateConnectionChannelFactory()

lstresult = svcProxy.LoadMyConnectionsXML()
rtvMyConnections.DataTextField = "ParentName"
rtvMyConnections.DataFieldParentID = "ParentId"
rtvMyConnections.DataFieldID = "Id"
rtvMyConnections.DataValueField = "Name"
rtvMyConnections.DataSource = lstresult
rtvMyConnections.DataBind()
```

Comment: did u try give width and heigh to radtreeview

Comment: It might be possible because of ParentID field value issue you are not able to see data in radtreeview. Please temporary set either null or zero in parentId field and check it.

Comment: yeah something to do with parentid..wil try it out. Thanks